# /js/mage cannot be crawled by Google - Security issues?

Tags: magento, web-crawler

the path "/js/mage" in Magento / our website cannot be crawled by Google (403 error).
It is not blocked by out robots.txt, the file rights are 775.

Does anybody know if this path is blocked due to security issues somewhere in the Magento configuration? And if there are no issues, how can I make this path to be crawled by Google?

Thanks in advance and merry x-mas

Alex

Answer (score 0):

Google provide a tool to check crawling's errors:
https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en

In that site you add your site and inside crawl/crawl errors you going to have a best idea of your problem with Google

I hope that this help you

regards
Emiliano